# Converting boolean integer to string value in javascript

Tags: boolean, type-conversion, boolean-operations

I am reading a boolean integer value from database (0 or 1).
Is there an simple solution to convert a boolean int to boolean string?

When I was saving the value to my database I was able convert the string to an int using a javascript ternary operator.

```
var i = result ? 1 : 0;
```

Is it possible to preform the opposite?

My current work-around is:

```
function boolIntToString(i) {
    if (i == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say 'string', but your function returns a boolean, unless you are going to add quotes around `true` and `false`.

Answer (score -1):

The expression `i != 0` evaluates to boolean false if i = 0, or true otherwise, so to get `true` or `false`, you could simply write:

```
var theBool = i != 0;
```

If you want a string, you can call `.toString()` on that boolean result. Wrapping this into your function, you get:

```js
function boolIntToString(i) {
  return (i != 0).toString();
}

console.log(boolIntToString(1));
```

Note that your own function returns a boolean, not a string.